# "@atlaskit/tooltip" does not work with Next.js

Tags: next.js, atlaskit

I'm using "@atlaskit/tooltip" with Next.js. The reproduction code is simple.

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@atlaskit/button';
import Tooltip from '@atlaskit/tooltip';

export default () => (
  <Tooltip content="Hello World">
    <Button>Hover Over Me</Button>
  </Tooltip>
);
```

But when I move the mouse over the button, there is no tooltip. How can I get them work together?

Comment: Hey, can you please share a reproducible example? Maybe a repository that I can clone and see the error.

Comment: Here is the repro: "https://github.com/jim-king-2000/nextbugrepro.git". Use the following command to run: "npm i&&npm run dev".

Comment: Taking a look now.

Comment: Forget it. I have switched to Grommet V2.

Comment: This might be a *tad* bit late, but try downgrading styled-components to 3.2.6. Atlaskit only supports that version.

Comment: Never late. But I only use the latest packages.